# Why doesn't this CSS create a new menu item when I hover?

Tags: html, css, menu

I followed a guide to make drop-down menus, even though I wanted them to pop to the right, instead of down. It doesn't work, though.

I'll put both CSS and HTML here.

Edit: Forgot that I can easily indent all the code in Vim, which makes it a LOT easier to copy all the text and get it in a code block.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sghRf/)

CSS:

```
#menubox
{
    width: 8%;
    height: 30%;
    border: 10% solid #C7D93D;
    border-radius: 5%;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 18%;
    font-family: Ubuntu, Lucida console, Futura;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}


#menubox ul li a
{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #FFF0A5;
}

#menubox ul li
{
    color: #468966;
    font-family: Ubuntu, Lucida console, Futura;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

#menubox ul
{
    color: #468966;
    font-family: Ubuntu, Lucida console, Futura;
}

#menubox ul ul
{
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    list-style: none;
}

#menubox ul ul li
{
    padding-top: 1px;
    float: none;
}

#menubox ul ul a
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#menubox ul li a:hover
{
    color: #FFB03B;
} 

#menubox ul li:hover ul
{
    left: 0;
}

#menubox ul li:hover a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menubox ul li:hover ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}


div p
{
    color: #FFF0A5;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 300px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

div ul ul
{
}


#circle
{
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #B64926;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 9%;
    margin-left: 52%;
    text-align: center;
}

#title
{
    text-color: #FFF0A5;
    font-size: 350%;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}

body
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #468966;
    font-family: Ubuntu, Lucida console, Futura;
}

.link
{
    text-color: #FFF0A5;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ID="menubox">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="http://folk.ntnu.no/arnstekl/" class="link">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Music</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://soundcloud.com/arnsteinkleven/" class="link">My music</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://folk.ntnu.no/arnstekl/gilberto.html" class="link">The Joao Gilberto project</a></li>
           </ul>

        <li><a href="https://www.github.com/arnstein" class="link">Github</a></li>

        <li><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/92472314@N03/" class="link">Pictures</a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>
    <div ID="circle">
        <p ID="title"> A <br> r <br> n <br> s <br> t <br> e <br> i <br> n </p>
    </div>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of the HTML involved?

Comment: Or add this in JSfiddle?

Comment: Please post your code in your question instead of linking: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'? Try and post more of your HTML code, and post your CSS onto this question to make it easier for us

Comment: @cfs Is there a way to get all code moved four spaces to the right? I don't want to do it to every line.

Comment: Notepad++ or Sublime Text, `Control+A` and press `tab` ;-)

Comment: @Arnstein If you're talking about the SO text editor, there is a button marked `{}` you could try (select the code snippet text first)

Comment: I'm moving away from ever using hover, since it doesn't work on most mobile devices.

Comment: @Mr.Manager That's a good point! What are some good alternatives? I don't really care about this site, as it's just a test site since I just learnt a bit of HTML and CSS, but it would be interesting to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing `li` tag before `ul`, but since the only valid child of a `ul` is `li`, you need to close it after.

```
<li><a href="#" class="link">Music</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="https://soundcloud.com/arnsteinkleven/" class="link">My music</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://folk.ntnu.no/arnstekl/gilberto.html" class="link">The Joao Gilberto project</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I forgot that after adding the new li's of course...! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery + JqueryUI. Look at the documentation. I used to be all about pure css and html.  Trying to minimize javascript as much as possible.  But, with so many modern sites (Facebook,Google) using javascript,jquery, etc... extensively. I'm moving towards using javascript to do most of my work, and css as to only set format.

Comment: This was a comment that got very long so I moved it to an answer.